# setPageTransformer() doesn't work with PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-animation, android-pageradapter

I want to customize animation of ViewPager. So I implements `ViewPager.PageTransformer` and call
`setPageTransformer()`. 
It worked well with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter`. But not `PagerAdapter`.

When I call `setPageTransformer()` (even though `PageTransformer` does nothing), the page in `PagerAdapter` display once and automatically dismiss (never display again) except the last one.
When I remove `setPageTransformer()`, it works normally.

Can anyone know why? Thanks in advance.
You can use the sample code in this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). I use `PagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

**EDIT** Here is [the code I changed](http://pastebin.com/LPCE9N4g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't work, because the sample code that you posted use Fragments.

In the API of `PagerAdapter` you can read:

> Base class providing the adapter to populate pages inside of a `ViewPager`. You will most likely want to use a more specific implementation of this, such as `FragmentPagerAdapter` or`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

When you implement a PagerAdapter, you must override the following methods at minimum:

```
instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)
destroyItem(ViewGroup, int, Object)
getCount()
isViewFromObject(View, Object)
```

So you can't just take the example and change `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `PagerAdpapter`.

**UPDATE 2014-01-14**

I import your code into an existing project where I show a `ViewPager`.

I think I found the mistake! 
Your Adapter works fine (also the `PageTransformater`).
Please change your method `instantiateItem` in `PagerAdper` to this and tell me if this is working for you:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.program_item, null);
    /** 
        // This line cause the strange behaviour
        view.setLayoutParams(mParams);
    **/
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img)).setImageResource(R.drawable.default_program);
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. From the sample, I create another PagerAdapter by extending this. And set this adapter for ViewPager.

Comment: Sorry in this case I can't give you more help...till now I always used  `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (-> with Fragments my UI is much more flexible for Phones and Tablets). I would suggest you to post a more precise question with codesnippets that show what you tried so far (or update this one). Without code or a log file people can just guess what`s the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer! Please try the solution and tell me if it works.

Comment: But I don't know if I set layout params. It doesn't work. Could you explain it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i tested it now and I can't explain this strange behaviour: if you set the `ViewPager.LayoutParams` all Views will be instatiated...but only the last View will be shown...

Comment: yes, it's so strange. Anyway, I can keep going with my project. Thanks for your time.